# after clicking button should be displayed permanently

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-hover

I am new in jQuery and I tried something. I created a container which holds a button. This button will be displayed if I am hovering the container. If I am hovering the button the css changed again and after a click a window occurred. This is working fine.

So here is the HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="button"><span>Button</span></div>
    <div class="window"></div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.holder').hover(function() {
        $('.button').css('display','block');
        $('.button').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('border','1px solid #999');
            $('.button span').css('color','#999');
        }, function() {
            $(this).css('border','1px solid #ccc');
            $('.button span').css('color','#ccc');
        });
    }, function() {
        $('.button').css('display','none');
    });
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.window').toggle();
        if ($('.window:visible').size() != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('.window').hide();
    });
    $('.window').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

And here is a DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9bf8f/15/

The problem is that the button has to be displayed permanently until the window is closed. Also when I leave the container (holder).

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you would like to stop the button from being hidden if it have been clicked you could change this:

```
$('.button').css('display', 'none');
```

to

```
$('.button:not(.active)').css('display', 'none');
```

and add the following in the buttons click method:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

This simply adds a new class to the button once it's clicked and only hides the button if this class isn't set.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bf8f/16/)

If you only wan't to stop the button from hiding when the `.window` div is visible you could simply use `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()`:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: That's quiet near to the solution I was searching for. But after the window is closed again the button has to has the same properties like before (if I am hovering or not hovering the container).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your solution. I solved the last problem above :)

Comment: Glad you solved it. What do you mean with "after the window is closed"?

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution with flags

I stored a flag named `var visibleFlag = false;` and I'm setting it according to what is needed

Whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/9bf8f/17/

Comment: That's quiet near to the solution I was searching for. But after closing the window the button should be displayed as long as I am hovering the container (holder).